# Unable to set the Image Url in listview array adapter

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using the API for getting the list of images and I am unable to set the Image array in ListView Array Adapter. Image is in the form String URL. Please see the below code What I have tried.

```
private void jsonParse() {
        String url = "This is the API URL";

        JsonObjectRequest objectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject photos = response.getJSONObject("photos"); //photos
                            JSONArray jsonArray = photos.getJSONArray("photo"); //photos.photo[0]

                            ImageView[] im = new ImageView[jsonArray.length()];

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject pics = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String id = pics.getString("id");
                                String server = pics.getString("server");
                                String farm = pics.getString("farm");
                                String secret = pics.getString("secret");


                                String URLs = "https://farm" + farm + ".staticflickr.com/" + server + "/" + id + "_" + secret + ".jpg";
                                System.out.println(URLs);
                                // Use Bitmap for converting the String form into Image Format
                                try {
                                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(URLs).getContent());
                                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }

                                im[i] = imageView;

                            }
                            //Below, 'im' is not readable by the ArrayAdapter
                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.image_layout,im); 
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

    }
```

ImageView[] 'im' array is not able to read by the ArrayAdapter. Can anyone please help me out of this problem?

> image_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_id"
        android:contentDescription="DefaultImage"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

> main_activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ffffff">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="430px"
            android:text="Click" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:padding="50px"
        android:id="@+id/list_view_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend to set image from the internet by using Glide or Picasso lib

https://github.com/bumptech/glide

```
Glide.with(this).load(url).into(imageView);
```

https://square.github.io/picasso/

```
Picasso.get().load(url).into(imageView);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have tried with Picasso also, but I am unable to send the Images using Array Adapter in Listview. See this `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.image_layout,im); listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
`

Comment: Basically you should implement custom adapter
https://abhiandroid.com/ui/listview
Here is example how to build custom adpater for list view but anyway i will recommend to change ListView for RecyclerView
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial on Listview and adapters,,,,, my requirement is just simple that's why I didn't want to use recycler view, I am just finding the way how can I store string url images into an array ,,,,,. Using bitmap or Picasso..... Can you please tell me how can we store images using Picasso in an valid array object ?? Otherwise it's too good to use the recycler view, I really appreciate your concern about this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you should use updated android api.you are in too old era

here is how to update your project

1. first use RecycelrView instead of listview
2. to fetch data from server api use Retrofit instead raw server api
   call.it damn easy
3. then use recyclerview adapter to show data.its easy and clean.